# Logistic Regression as multiclass classification using PySpark and issues

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, multiclass-classification, pyspark

I am trying to use `Logistic Regression` to classify the datasets which has *Sparse Vector* in feature vector:

**Case 1**: I tried using the pipeline of ML in MLLIB as follow:

```
# used libraries
from pyspark.ml.feature import HashingTF
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression

print(type(trainingData)) # for checking only
print(trainingData.take(2)) # To see the details of dataset
lr = LogisticRegression(labelCol="label", featuresCol="features", maxIter=maximumIteration,     regParam=re
gParamValue)
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[lr])
# Train model
model = pipeline.fit(trainingData)
```

Got the following error:

```
<class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>
[Row(label=2.0, features=SparseVector(2000, {51: 1.0, 160: 1.0, 341: 1.0, 417: 1.0, 561: 1.0, 656: 1.0, 863: 1.0, 939: 1.0, 1021: 1.0, 1324: 1.0, 1433: 1.0, 1573: 1.0, 1604: 1.0, 1720: 1.0})), Row(label=3.0, features=SparseVector(2000, {24: 1.0, 51: 2.0, 119: 1.0, 167: 1.0, 182: 1.0, 190: 1.0, 195: 1.0, 285: 1.0, 432: 1.0, 539: 1.0, 571: 1.0, 630: 1.0, 638: 1.0, 656: 1.0, 660: 2.0, 751: 1.0, 785: 1.0, 794: 1.0, 801: 1.0, 823: 1.0, 893: 1.0, 900: 1.0, 915: 1.0, 956: 1.0, 966: 1.0, 1025: 1.0, 1029: 1.0, 1035: 1.0, 1038: 1.0, 1093: 1.0, 1115: 2.0, 1147: 1.0, 1206: 1.0, 1252: 1.0, 1261: 1.0, 1262: 1.0, 1268: 1.0, 1304: 1.0, 1351: 1.0, 1378: 1.0, 1423: 1.0, 1437: 1.0, 1441: 1.0, 1530: 1.0, 1534: 1.0, 1556: 1.0, 1562: 1.0, 1604: 1.0, 1711: 1.0, 1737: 1.0, 1750: 1.0, 1776: 1.0, 1858: 1.0, 1865: 1.0, 1923: 1.0, 1926: 1.0, 1959: 1.0, 1999: 1.0}))]
16/08/25 19:14:07 ERROR org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression: Currently, LogisticRegression with E
lasticNet in ML package only supports binary classification. Found 5 in the input dataset.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/LR/test.py", line 260, in <module>
    accuracy = TrainLRCModel(trainData, testData)
  File "/home/LR/test.py", line 211, in TrainLRCModel
    model = pipeline.fit(trainingData)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/pipeline.py", line 69, in fit
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/pipeline.py", line 213, in _fit
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/pipeline.py", line 69, in fit
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py", line 133, in _fit
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py", line 130, in _fit_java
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 45, in deco
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o207.fit.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Currently, LogisticRegression with ElasticNet in ML package only supports binary
 classification. Found 5 in the input dataset.
        at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression.train(LogisticRegression.scala:290)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression.train(LogisticRegression.scala:159)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:71)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Case 2**: I search the possible alternate solution of above one and got that `LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS` will work on multi-class classificaton, I tried as follow:

```
#used library
from pyspark.mllib.classification import LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS, LogisticRegressionModel, LogisticRegressionWithSGD
print(type(trainingData)) # for checking only
print(trainingData.take(2)) # to see the dataset
model = LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS.train(trainingData, numClasses=5)
print(type(model))
```

Got the following error:

```
<class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>
[Row(label=3.0, features=SparseVector(2000, {24: 1.0, 51: 2.0, 119: 1.0, 167: 1.0, 182: 1.0, 190: 1.0, 195: 1.0, 28
5: 1.0, 432: 1.0, 539: 1.0, 571: 1.0, 630: 1.0, 638: 1.0, 656: 1.0, 660: 2.0, 751: 1.0, 785: 1.0, 794: 1.0, 801: 1.
0, 823: 1.0, 893: 1.0, 900: 1.0, 915: 1.0, 956: 1.0, 966: 1.0, 1025: 1.0, 1029: 1.0, 1035: 1.0, 1038: 1.0, 1093: 1.
0, 1115: 2.0, 1147: 1.0, 1206: 1.0, 1252: 1.0, 1261: 1.0, 1262: 1.0, 1268: 1.0, 1304: 1.0, 1351: 1.0, 1378: 1.0, 14
23: 1.0, 1437: 1.0, 1441: 1.0, 1530: 1.0, 1534: 1.0, 1556: 1.0, 1562: 1.0, 1604: 1.0, 1711: 1.0, 1737: 1.0, 1750: 1
.0, 1776: 1.0, 1858: 1.0, 1865: 1.0, 1923: 1.0, 1926: 1.0, 1959: 1.0, 1999: 1.0})), Row(label=5.0, features=SparseV
ector(2000, {103: 1.0, 310: 1.0, 601: 1.0, 817: 1.0, 866: 1.0, 940: 1.0, 1023: 1.0, 1118: 1.0, 1339: 1.0, 1447: 1.0
, 1634: 1.0, 1776: 1.0}))]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/LR/test.py", line 260, in <module>
    accuracy = TrainLRCModel(trainData, testData)
  File "/home/LR/test.py", line 230, in TrainLRCModel
    model = LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS.train(trainingData, numClasses=5)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/classification.py", line 382, in train
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/regression.py", line 206, in _regression_train_wrapper
TypeError: data should be an RDD of LabeledPoint, but got <class 'pyspark.sql.types.Row'>
```

Again I tried to convert the dataset into RDD of Labeled Point as follow i.e case 3:

**Case 3**: Converted the dataset into RDD of Labeled Point so that I can use `LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS` as follow:

```
    #used library
    from pyspark.mllib.classification import LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS, LogisticRegressionModel, LogisticRegressionWithSGD
    from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint

    print(type(trainingData)) # For checking only
    print(trainingData.take(2)) # To see the datasets
    trainingData = trainingData.map(lambda row:[LabeledPoint(row.label,row.features)])
    print('type of trainingData')
    print(type(trainingData))
    print(trainingData.take(2))
    model = LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS.train(trainingData, numClasses=5)
    print(type(model))
```

Got the following error:

```
<class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>
[Row(label=2.0, features=SparseVector(2000, {51: 1.0, 160: 1.0, 341: 1.0, 417: 1.0, 561: 1.0, 656: 1.0, 863: 1.0, 9
39: 1.0, 1021: 1.0, 1324: 1.0, 1433: 1.0, 1573: 1.0, 1604: 1.0, 1720: 1.0})), Row(label=3.0, features=SparseVector(
2000, {24: 1.0, 51: 2.0, 119: 1.0, 167: 1.0, 182: 1.0, 190: 1.0, 195: 1.0, 285: 1.0, 432: 1.0, 539: 1.0, 571: 1.0, 
630: 1.0, 638: 1.0, 656: 1.0, 660: 2.0, 751: 1.0, 785: 1.0, 794: 1.0, 801: 1.0, 823: 1.0, 893: 1.0, 900: 1.0, 915: 
1.0, 956: 1.0, 966: 1.0, 1025: 1.0, 1029: 1.0, 1035: 1.0, 1038: 1.0, 1093: 1.0, 1115: 2.0, 1147: 1.0, 1206: 1.0, 12
52: 1.0, 1261: 1.0, 1262: 1.0, 1268: 1.0, 1304: 1.0, 1351: 1.0, 1378: 1.0, 1423: 1.0, 1437: 1.0, 1441: 1.0, 1530: 1
.0, 1534: 1.0, 1556: 1.0, 1562: 1.0, 1604: 1.0, 1711: 1.0, 1737: 1.0, 1750: 1.0, 1776: 1.0, 1858: 1.0, 1865: 1.0, 1
923: 1.0, 1926: 1.0, 1959: 1.0, 1999: 1.0}))]
type of trainingData
<class 'pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD'>
[[LabeledPoint(2.0, (2000,[51,160,341,417,561,656,863,939,1021,1324,1433,1573,1604,1720],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1
.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]))], [LabeledPoint(3.0, (2000,[24,51,119,167,182,190,195,285,432,539,571,630,638,656
,660,751,785,794,801,823,893,900,915,956,966,1025,1029,1035,1038,1093,1115,1147,1206,1252,1261,1262,1268,1304,1351,
1378,1423,1437,1441,1530,1534,1556,1562,1604,1711,1737,1750,1776,1858,1865,1923,1926,1959,1999],[1.0,2.0,1.0,1.0,1.
0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,2.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,2.0,1.0,1.0,1
.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]))]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/LR/test.py", line 260, in <module>
    accuracy = TrainLRCModel(trainData, testData)
  File "/home/LR/test.py", line 230, in TrainLRCModel
    model = LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS.train(trainingData, numClasses=5)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/classification.py", line 381, in train
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'features'
```

Can someone please suggest where I am missing something, I wanted to use the Logistic Regression in PySpark and classify the multi-class classification.

Currently I am using spark version `version 1.6.2` and python version `Python 2.7.9` on google cloud.

Thanking you in advance for you kind help.

Comment: Did you see the [documented examples](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/mllib-linear-methods.html#logistic-regression) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30925819/from-dataframe-to-rddlabeledpoint) question? Try something like `trainingData.map(row => LabeledPoint(row.label, row.features))`

Comment: @Emre, Thanks for your suggestion, Yes I have gone above [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/mllib-linear-methods.html#logistic-regression)  and also found relevant [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33551747/logistic-regression-mllib-pyspark-issue-with-multiple-labels), but their feature vector is not Spark Vector, In my case feature is `Spark Vector`, I think this is the issue. `trainingData.map(row => LabeledPoint(row.label, row.features))` this is **Scala** sentence and corresponding in PySpark I already tried in **case 3**.

Comment: You have at least two problems: trying to use logistic regression for a multi-class problem, and mixing spark.mllib classes with the spark.ml API.

Comment: @SeanOwen Yes, I am trying logistic regression for a multi-class problem, but not mixing the `spark.mllib` classes with `spark.ml` API, I have written these  cases separately. For full details of code and error output, please check my [github repo](https://github.com/krishnaiitd/LogisticRegression), Also created README for understanding, could you please check and do let me know where I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Try omitting the `[]` so that you do *not* create python list

```
trainingData = trainingData.map(lambda row: LabeledPoint(row.label,row.features))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
trainingData = trainingData.map(lambda row: LabeledPoint(row.label,**list**(row.features)))
```